# Information about $T$ if $T^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What can we say about $T$ if $T^2=0$? How can we prove that it has zero as an eigenvalue?

Comment: If $T \neq 0$, then $\exists x$ such that $Tx \neq 0$, and $T(Tx) = 0$, so $0$ is an eigen-value with eigen-vector $Tx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If  $T \ne 0$, then there is a non-zero vector $\mathbf v$ such that $T\mathbf v \ne 0$, and then $T(T\mathbf v) = T^2\mathbf v = 0$, showing that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with eigenvector $T\mathbf v$.  In fact *every* eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$, since if $T \mathbf v = \lambda \mathbf v$ for nonzero $\mathbf v$, then $0 = T^2\mathbf v = \lambda^2 \mathbf v$, so since $\mathbf v \ne 0$, $\lambda^2 = 0$, whence $\lambda =0$ as well.

More can be said about $T$:  for example, $I \pm T$ is invertible, since $(I + T)(I -T) = I^2 - T^2 = I$.    The list of "what we can say about T" can be on the long side, so having shown $0$ is an eigenvalue, per specific request, I'll leave further facts for those who seek them to discover.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

If $T^2=0$, then $det(T^2)=det(0)=0$.  But as $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$, we now see that $det(T)^2=0$, so $det(T)=0$.  As $det(T)$ is the product of all eigenvalues for $T$, we see that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: Can you do it without determinants? I know it's not necessary, but we haven't been using them in my Linear Algebra class.

Answer (score 2):

Doc's solution is great if your vector space is finite-dimensional.  If you have something bigger like a Hilbert space, you can do this:

The kernel of $T^2$ is the whole vector space, so the image of $T$ is contained entirely within the kernel of $T$.  If the kernel of $T$ is just $0$, then the image of $T$ is just $0$, a contradiction.  Hence the kernel of $T$ is nontrivial, and there is therefore a nonzero vector in the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue zero (and thus zero is an eigenvalue).

Answer (score 2):

*Any* linear transformation of $V$ to $V$ with nonzero kernel has $0$ as an eigenvalue. If there exists $x\neq 0$ such that $T(x)=0$, then certainly $T(x)=0x$.

There are two cases:

Case 1: $T(x)=0$ for all $x$, whence any nonzero $x$ is an eigenvector for $0$ or

Case 2: $T(x)\neq 0$ for some $x\neq 0$, whence $T(T(x))=0$, and $T(x)$ is an eigenvector for $0$.